# tensorflow Invalid symbol

Tags: python, tensorflow, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I am using seq2seq to train a language model on some english words not found in the dictionary.
But when I train the model on a phonetic dictionary I get these warnings, then the model wont recognize the words after training because it cant recognize these letters.

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Invalid symbol:A
WARNING:tensorflow:Invalid symbol:O
WARNING:tensorflow:Invalid symbol:O
WARNING:tensorflow:Invalid symbol:C
WARNING:tensorflow:Invalid symbol:I
WARNING:tensorflow:Invalid symbol:A
WARNING:tensorflow:Invalid symbol:O
WARNING:tensorflow:Invalid symbol:O
WARNING:tensorflow:Invalid symbol:C
WARNING:tensorflow:Invalid symbol:C
WARNING:tensorflow:Invalid symbol:I
WARNING:tensorflow:Invalid symbol:E
WARNING:tensorflow:Invalid symbol:C
WARNING:tensorflow:Invalid symbol:O
WARNING:tensorflow:Invalid symbol:I
WARNING:tensorflow:Invalid symbol:I
WARNING:tensorflow:Invalid symbol:E
WARNING:tensorflow:Invalid symbol:E
WARNING:tensorflow:Invalid symbol:E
WARNING:tensorflow:Invalid symbol:O
WARNING:tensorflow:Invalid symbol:O
```

Any help would be appreciated Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am gonna go ahead and answer my own question if someone needs help,
The problem was that I needed to add the missing letters to vocab.g2p.
Edit: added CAPITAL LETTERS to vocab.g2p